# How to find a subdocument by id in mongoose and exclude some fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the a document stored in mongodb:

```
shop: {
  _id: '...'
  title: 'my shop'
  users: [
    {
      _id: '...',
      name: 'user1',
      username: '...'
    },
    {
      _id: '...',
      name: 'user2',
      username: '...'
    }
  ]
}
```

I use this query to get a subdocument user by his id:

```
Shop.findOne({'users._id': userId}, {'users.$': 1}, function (err, user) {
  console.log(user);
});
```

Output:

```
{ _id: ...,
  users: 
   [{
     name: 'user1',
     username: '...',
     _id: ...
    }]
}
```

How can I filter the result to only return the user name.
The way I do it now:

```
Shop.findOne({'users._id': userId}, {'users.$': 1}, function (err, shop) {
  shop = shop.toObject()
  user = shop.users[0]
  filtered = {
    name: user.name
  }
  callback(filtered);
});
```

But is there a better way to do it all in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try mongodb aggregation framework with mongoose:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate-js

I suggest you first apply **unwind** users and then **match** the user id and then **project** the username.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this method, maybe litte example, to use it woul be appreciate

Answer (score 7):

This question is almost two years old, but I noticed that people are still looking for a solution to this problem. fernandopasik's answer helped me very much, but is missing a code sample on how to use the suggested aggregation operations. That's why I post a more detailed answer.
The document I used is:

```
{
  _id: '...'
  title: 'my shop'
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'user1Id',
      name: 'user1',
      username: '...'
    },
    {
      _id: 'user2Id',
      name: 'user2',
      username: '...'
    }
  ]
}
```

The solution I came up with (after reading the mongodb docs about aggregation) was:

```
Shop.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$users'},
  {$match: {'users._id': 2}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, 'name': '$users.name'}}
]);
```

To understand how the aggregation is working, it's best to try one operation at a time and read the mongodb docs of this operation.

1. `Shop.aggregate([{$unwind: '$users'}])`

**$unwind** deconstructs the users array (don't forget to include $ on the array name), so you end up with:

```
{
  _id: '...',
  title: 'my shop',
  users: {
    _id: 'user1Id',
    name: 'user1',
    username: '...'
  }
}
{
  _id: '...',
  title: 'my shop',
  users: {
    _id: 'user2Id',
    name: 'user2',
    username: '...'
  }
}
```

2. Using `{$match: {'users._id': 'user2Id'}}` on the aggregation pipeline (the two docs in this example) will return the whole document where users._id is 'user2Id':

```
{
  _id: '...',
  title: 'my shop',
  users: {
    _id: 'user2Id',
    name: 'user2',
    username: '...'
  }
}
```

3. to return only name: 'user2' you can use `{$project: {_id: 0, 'name': '$users.name'}}`:

```
{name: 'user2'}
```

The aggregation pipeline is not easy to grasp at first. I recommend reading through the mongodb aggregation docs and try one aggregation operation at a time. It is sometimes hard to spot the error in the whole aggregation pipeline. Most of the time you simply get no result document from the pipeline when there is an error somewhere in the pipeline.